# Swift - Logic for adding a "bonus streak"

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

In Swift, I have a simple 'game' that tallys up a score based on a certain button in the UI that is pressed. 15 normal buttons. 1 "streak broken" button. once the "streak broken" button is tapped, the score should reflect the score, with the added streak bonus.

It works fine, until a normal button is pressed. Then my streak gets zero'd out, thus adding the score incorrectly on the next "normal button" press.

**Here is my log:**

```
Streak counter: 1 / Bonus point total: 0 / Score total: 3 / TOTAL SCORE: 3
Streak counter: 2 / Bonus point total: 0 / Score total: 6 / TOTAL SCORE: 6
Streak counter: 3 / Bonus point total: 0 / Score total: 9 / TOTAL SCORE: 9
Streak counter: 4 / Bonus point total: 0 / Score total: 12 / TOTAL SCORE: 12
Streak counter: 5 / Bonus point total: 0 / Score total: 15 / TOTAL SCORE: 15
Streak counter: 6 / Bonus point total: 0 / Score total: 18 / TOTAL SCORE: 18
Streak counter: 7 / Bonus point total: 2 / Score total: 21 / TOTAL SCORE: 23
Streak counter: 8 / Bonus point total: 4 / Score total: 24 / TOTAL SCORE: 28
Streak counter: 9 / Bonus point total: 6 / Score total: 27 / TOTAL SCORE: 33
STREAK BROKEN!
Streak counter: 1 / Bonus point total: 0 / Score total: 30 / TOTAL SCORE: 30
```

You can see that once the STREAK BROKEN! button gets tapped, the scores don't properly add up on the next normal button press. The TOTAL SCORE should be 36 (+3 for a normal tap / 0 for streak bonus.) not 30.

**Normal button pressed code:**

```
// Calculate the addition of a score:
normalScore += 3

// Calculate the streak:
streakCounter += 1

switch  streakCounter {
case 1...6:
    bonusPointTotal += 0  
case 7...9:
    bonusPointTotal += 2
case 10...12:
    bonusPointTotal += 3
case 13...16:
    bonusPointTotal += 4
default:
    bonusPointTotal += 0
 }
bonusLabelCounter.text = "+\(bonusPointTotal)"   
totalScore = (normalScore + bonusPointTotal)  
scoreLabelCounter.text = "\(totalScore)"    
print("Streak counter: \(streakCounter) / Bonus point total: \(bonusPointTotal) / Score total: \(normalScore) / TOTAL SCORE: \(totalScore)")
```

**STREAK BROKEN button pressed**

```
totalScore = (normalScore + bonusPointTotal)
// Reset the streak:
streakCounter = 0
print("STREAK BROKEN!")
bonusPointTotal = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's the thing: You set the `bonusPointTotal` to 0 then when you press again you add 0 to the normal score (30).

The problem is in your **Streak Broken** code.

First of all, setting the `totalScore` is useless since you will set it again when pressing a normal button and you don't use it before the normal button press.

Second of all, I believe fixing your code is just a matter of replacing the first line of **Streak Broken**. So replace `totalScore = (normalScore + bonusPointTotal)` with `normalScore = totalScore`.

Let me explain the logic in your case. Right before breaking the streak you have **a total** of 33. You break the streak and set the bonus to 0. Normally (with your code) the **total score** will be lower (30) than before (33). But if you set the **normal score** to **total score** when you break the streak you will then have a **normal score** of 33. Then you add the 3 from the normal button press and you get **a total** of 36 (with bonus 0 and normal 36).

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for that!! The solution worked perfectly, and your logic made complete sense. I don't know how I was overlooking that, but alas, i did. Great job!